# Order by meta_key field in Wordpress not meta_value field value

Tags: posts, wp-query

I have a requirement where I need to show all posts having thumbnail first and  ordered by title and then remaining posts ordered by title
Below is the code I tried

```
$the_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : -1;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => "listings",
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        //'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 88,
        'paged' => $the_page,

        'orderby' => 'meta_key title',
    'meta_query' => array(  //query post based on meta key
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR', // add condition if meta key is exists or not
            array(
                'key' => '_thumbnail_id', 
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' // include post without _thumbnail_id key
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_thumbnail_id', 
                'compare' => 'NOT NULL' // include post without _thumbnail_id key
            )
        )
    )
```

If we look closely , I have set `orderby='meta_key title'` and `meta_key` is not one of supported arguments in [WP_Query Documnentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) hence its being removed by WP_Query while generating sql.

In generated sql only `ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title DESC` is generated.

My question is: 
 1. do we have any other way to get posts with thumbnail first in the list ? 
 2. do we have a way to order result by field that is not listed in WP_Query supported arguments list ?

Any help or hint is appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just do a query with `orderby' => 'title'` and then use an if statement (`if (the_post_thumbnail)`) to separate the results into 2 different arrays.  Now just foreach through the array that has thumbnails, then the array that doesn't.  Or put the results in a variable ($thumbs, $nothumbs) and then echo out each variable

Comment: @rudtek, thanks for the input but this won't work with pagination I guess.Post with thumb will be there on each page on top this way and not on first page all together.